# trying to achieve arrow pointing upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to create an arrow pointing upwards.
I am trying to to do this in purely css.

I am not able to reproduce in my fiddle as it uses scss.
But thought It may help and provide more information.
http://jsfiddle.net/311s1whu/4/

I have currently created trapezium shape, which is not quite what I would like. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RRFR1WHZDYTF6LTQ/edit

This is the scss that I have tried:

```
     .icon__controls__controls {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      margin-right: 2.1276595745%;
      width: 36.170212766%;
      margin-left: 38.2978723404%;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      text-align: center; }
      .icon__controls__controls:last-child {
        margin-right: 0; }
      .icon__controls__controls [class^=icon-] {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        *vertical-align: auto;
        color: #666;
        margin: 0 5px;
        vertical-align: top; }
      .icon__controls__controls .zoom-out {
        color: red; }
      .icon__controls__controls:after {
        display: none;
        content: '';
        z-index: 3;
        border: 50px solid transparent;
        /* border-left: 5px solid transparent;
                border-right: 5px solid transparent;

                border-bottom: 5px solid black; */ }
      .icon__controls__controls:after {
        border-top-color: #ef6f00; }
      .icon__controls__controls.active:after {
        display: block; }
```

Comment: I think your fiddle is missing some things, i can't see anything.

Comment: You're trying to use SASS in jsfiddle. Please insert the rendered CSS, then we can help you.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: yeah it doesnt work in fiddle

Comment: @CameronMartin yeah thats the reason i gave u part of code

Comment: @pruhuram are you aware that you have to compile SASS to CSS before a browser can render it?

Comment: I compiled your code and got an `Undefined variable: "$icons-selector". ` message. Fix that, compile and see if that works

Comment: @Fabio: its ok if you remove that part of property from css...the problem is not there its not showing triangle

Comment: You can choose SCSS under Languages, SASS works in jsfiddle just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/tsC7D/23/

Comment: @coma: i changed it but i am not able too see the triangle

Comment: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ Go there and learn by example

Comment: the point is nobody can see a thing, so how are we supposed to help? Based on what you provided, your problem is the code renders absolutely nothing. This is because no matter what we tell you, you're stubborn on a "no, I won't help you guys to help me". I know your SCSS MIGHT be correct.... if you show the entire code. Right now, it isn't, it doesn't compile, hence it doesn't work. Either way, the easiest, fastest way was to do what @CameronMartin told you: to insert CSS rendered code

Comment: @coma Wasn't aware of that. Well the problem is that there is no definition of `$icons-selector` in the example you have given.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is described here, works for me and looks much simpler than what you have going on.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```
.arrow-up {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;

border-bottom: 5px solid black;
```

}